# create batch file for checking .net framework 3.5 sp1 is installed or not

Tags: .net, batch-file, .net-3.5

I want to know how to create batch file for check .net `framework 3.5 sp1` is installed or not in system.
    Please Help.

Comment: This is a duplicate! Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492967/is-there-a-dos-command-for-verifying-what-version-of-net-is-installed

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question wants to know what version is installed not IF it is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the folder %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 exists.

In your batch file, it could looks like:

```
IF EXIST "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5" ECHO File exists!
```

And here is a list of other possibilites: http://www.walkernews.net/2008/05/16/how-to-check-net-framework-version-installed/