# Script to check Workstation Details and Software Components

Tags: windows, components, settings

Hello StackOverflow Community

I'd like to create some sort of a skript that gathers information on a PC when executed.

I am currently rolling out a new version of Asset Management Tool "PAS". The Process includes many tasks that might be executed by a skript.

The details I would like to check before I start my installation are:
- Domain-Name
- User-Domain-Name of the PC
- Windows Version and bit-Version (32 vs 64)
- Is .NET Framework 4 or higher installed? (which version)
- Which MS Office-Version is used?
- Our Programm consists of many .dll's -> I would like to compare our most recent package to the installed package and receive an "Outdated" list.

A skript would save me a lot of time, as I need to the above on a couple of hundrets of PC's...

Unfortunately I don't have much programming knowledge, but am absolutely willing to read/learn the need. What I need to know is if it CAN be achieved and what would be a good medium to create such a skript (.bat?). I don't really know where to start.

Maybe somebody can give me a hint where to start? :)

Many thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got one step further and found out, how I can check the version of a Software in the cmd and tested it, it works fine:

```
wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft .Net%'" get Name, Version
```

(Answer found here: 
[Is there a command line command for verifying what version of .NET is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492967/is-there-a-dos-command-for-verifying-what-version-of-net-is-installed) )

So, as don't know anything else, I will try to get this done in a batch (.bat) File. If you know better ways to choose than a batch file, please leave your comments!

So after a lot of Googling I got together a package of some commands, that will help me make the necessary system queries.

At the moment the script looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD..
DEL Version.txt
wmic os get name, OSArchitecture>Version.txt
wmic cpu get Name>>Version.txt
wmic netuse get Name>>Version.txt
%userdomain%>>Version.txt
wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft .Net Framework 4%%'" get Name, Version>>Version.txt
wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008%%'" get Name, Version>>Version.txt
"sqlcmd -L">>Version.txt
wmic product where "Name like 'Micro Focus Server 5%%'" get Name, Version>>Version.txt
if exist C:\PAS2\local goto end else mkdir C:\PAS2\local
end:
```

---

...and the output (Version.txt) looks like this:

---

```
Name                                                                       OSArchitecture  
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional |C:\windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2  64-Bit          
Name                                      
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz  
Name                    
\\brns01\PUBLIC (M:)    
\\brns01\DISTRIBU (N:)  
\\brns01\DOCUMENT (O:)  
\\brns01\PROJECTS (P:)  
\\BRNS01\PRITRANS (U:)  
\\Brns01\USERS\GN (L:)  
Name                                                 Version    
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack  4.5.50932  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack    4.5.50710  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK - DEU Lang Pack     4.5.50710  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK                     4.5.50710  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack      4.0.30319  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 RC                    4.5.50861  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 RC (DEU)              4.5.50861  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK                   4.5.51641  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK (Deutsch)         4.5.51641  
Name                                          Version       
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2-Setup (Deutsch)  10.52.4000.0  
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RsFx Driver      10.52.4000.0  
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2-Richtlinien      10.50.1600.1  
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client    10.52.4000.0  
Name                    Version     
Micro Focus Server 5.1  5.107.0047
```

---

**Current Status**:

Version Check .NetFramework:   DONE!

Version Check MS SQL Server:   DONE!

Version Check Micro Focus 5:   DONE!

Version and Bit Check Windows: DONE!

Check Domain Name:             OPEN! (%userdomain% works in cmd, but not in my script)

Check Current User Domain Name:OPEN! (dont know how yet)

Check Running SQL Instances: OPEN! ("sqlcmd -L" works in cmd, but not in my script. I have a very strange behaviour here. In CMD: when I use the Syntax sqlcmd -l it doesn't work, with sqlcmd -L [captial Letter] it works as intended. Strange, I was under the impression, that the syntax is not case-sensitive. When I use the command sqlcmd -L in my batch-file it generates a long string of chineses symbols and all following tasks are not beeing executed, when I use "sqlcmd -L" as in the code listed above, it does not generate an output into my file)

Check existence of a c:\pas2\local and create directory if it does not exist: I think it works :)

I will re-comment when I have solved some of the above issues. If you guys have tips to improve my script, please do not hesitate to comment! Thanks!

Cheers
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Update Domain Name:
Error was, that I forgot to put echo in front of %userdomain%, also the batch-file "eats" the first % sign (why?) so I always have to put two of them. The correct, working string in the batch-file is:

```
echo %%userdomain%%>>Version.txt
```

...and in the text-file it appears as follows:

```
BRNS
```

...which is our domain