# Future-proofing the .NET version detection

Tags: c#, .net, detection

Not to beat the [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139891/whats-the-foolproof-way-to-tell-which-versions-of-net-are-installed-on-a-prod) [horse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed), however,  I am looking for a way to detect the installed .NET frameworks.  It seems like the provided solutions (in the links) are all good up until the point a new version of the framework is released and then all bets are off.  The reason for this is that the detection relies on the registry keys and it seems that v4 of the framework has broken the convention and one now has to take extra steps to detect v4.

Is there a way to detect the .NET framework that will also work when .NET v5 appears.

EDIT: Ok, for future generations of frustrated .NET Version seekers, here is the code to make it happen:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;

private List<string> GetInstalledDotNetFrameworks()
{
    string key = string.Empty;
    string version = string.Empty;
    List<string> frameworks = new List<string>();

    var matches = Registry.LocalMachine
                .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP")
                .GetSubKeyNames().Where(keyname => Regex.IsMatch(keyname, @"^v\d"));


    // special handling for v4.0 (deprecated) and v4 (has subkeys with info)
    foreach (var item in matches)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case "v4.0":  // deprecated - ignore
                break;

            case "v4":// get more info from subkeys

                key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\" + item;
                string[] subkeys = Registry.LocalMachine
                    .OpenSubKey(key)
                    .GetSubKeyNames();


                foreach (var subkey in subkeys)
                {
                    key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\" + item + @"\" + subkey;
                    version = Registry.LocalMachine
                            .OpenSubKey(key)
                            .GetValue("Version").ToString();

                    version = string.Format("{0} ({1})", version, subkey);
                    frameworks.Add(version);
                }


                break;
            case "v1.1.4322":   // special case, as the framework does not follow convention
                frameworks.Add(item);
                break;
            default:

                try
                {
                    // get the Version value
                    key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\" + item;
                    version = Registry.LocalMachine
                            .OpenSubKey(key)
                            .GetValue("Version").ToString();

                    frameworks.Add(version);

                }
                catch
                {
                    // most likely new .NET Framework got introduced and broke the convention
                }

                break;

        }

    }

    // sort the list, just in case the registry was not sorted
    frameworks.Sort();

    return frameworks;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can use this approximately (see below for more complete solution):

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
    .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP")
    .GetSubKeyNames().Where(keyname=>Regex.IsMatch(keyname,@"^v\d"))
```

On my machine, this returns: v2.0.50727, v3.0, v3.5, v4, v4.0.  Subkeys could be used to detect service packs (which are probably relevant).  Also, using the key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework` returns v2.0.50727, v3.0 and v4.0.30319 - ehhh, lovely, slightly different!

There's no guarantee this pattern will hold, but it's a pretty reasonable bet :-).  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785 has some more info on the details of the registry describing the versioning, and in particular, you *may* need to check for `Install` - but that's tricky as v4.0 demonstrates.

***Edit:*** I've extended this to detect arbitrary sub-key's of the registry that include installation info so as to detect v4 Client and Full profiles correctly.  Also, the `RegistryKey` type is `IDisposable`, and it looks like the Dispose method is indeed doing something (registry key unlocking).

```
var versionList = new List<string>();
using(var ndpKey=Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP")) {
    Action<RegistryKey, Action<RegistryKey,string>> processKids = (node, action) => {
        foreach(var childname in node.GetSubKeyNames())
            using(var child = node.OpenSubKey(childname))
                action(child,childname);
    };

    Action<RegistryKey, Func<RegistryKey, bool>> visitDescendants = null;
    visitDescendants = (regkey, isDone) => {
        if(!isDone(regkey))
            processKids(regkey, (subkey, subkeyname)=>visitDescendants(subkey,isDone));
    };

    processKids(ndpKey, (versionKey, versionKeyName) => {
        if(Regex.IsMatch(versionKeyName,@"^v\d")) {
            visitDescendants(versionKey, key => {
                bool isInstallationNode = Equals(key.GetValue("Install"), 1) && key.GetValue("Version") != null;
                if(isInstallationNode)
                    versionList.Add(
                        key.Name.Substring(ndpKey.Name.Length+1) 
                        + (key.GetValue("SP")!=null ? ", service pack "+ key.GetValue("SP"):"")
                        + " ("+key.GetValue("Version")  +") "
                    );
                return isInstallationNode;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

versionList then contains:

```
v2.0.50727, service pack 2 (2.0.50727.4927)   
v3.0, service pack 2 (3.0.30729.4926)   
v3.5, service pack 1 (3.5.30729.4926)   
v4\Client (4.0.30319)   
v4\Full (4.0.30319)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this registry key - thought I had to go to  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP.  I think this might just do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't actually work.  Software/Microsoft/.NETFramework does not list v3.5

Comment: Fixed - i'm using the NDP registry key now.

Comment: Yep, there is some trickery involved for the v4.0 key - there is client and full installs to contend with.  Plus the v4 key is deprecated.

Comment: Btw, this fails with v1.1 as it does not pop in the Version value.  I updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Do you expect we can tell you the future? :) Why do you need that in the first place? I mean, if you write an app for v4, what difference does it make if v5 is installed or not? You can specify in the app.config what versions you support, but you can't know in advance what the next version will be, or even if your app will run on that. Whenever a new framework comes out, you'll have to test your app, and decide if you want to migrate or not. If you migrate, then you make changes to the app.config and possibly the code, too, and release a new version. If you don't, then you'll still require that an older framework version be installed. It's not like v5 comes out and people will start uninstalling all the previous frameworks. I still have v1.1 and v2 on my machine and I guess they'll stick around for a while.

Comment: That's not the point - the data is not used by my application.  However, because my app is used by a huge number of people in my organization, the powers that be decided to use my application as a way to collect information on the capabilities of users' machines (e.g. cpu, ram, hd space, etc...), including the .NET framework.  It seems like I have to rewrite this routine every year or two because the detection mechanism changes.  I'd like to put that in the past and have something that works going forward.

Answer (score 3):

I am in agreement with fejesjoco.  Why do you even want to detect a future version that your code has not been compiled against?

If you look in the Framework folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework) you will see that all previous versions of the Framework are install along with the most recent version.  If your code is compiled against 4.0 and 5.0 comes out it will still have a folder for 4.0.

If you could give us a bit more context as to why you want to detect future versions we may be able to help you better.

Comment: See the context in my comment for @fejesjoco's answer.

Comment: OK that makes a bit more sense.  Why do you not loop through the registry key under the relevant .Net folder to pick up the versions of the Framework that are installed? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\[v2.0|v3.0|v4.0.30319] . I would guess the next version of the framework is going to get v4.5 or v5.0 should be simple enough to do, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Include an auto-update feature in the detection tool?